# CRM 2013 - Incident Resolution - Retrieve New Status Reason

Tags: c#, javascript, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm looking for a way (either plugins or JavaScript) to retrieve the NEW statuscode of an incident when it gets resolved.

What I'm trying to do is set a date field on the incident depending on the status code selected in the incident resolution dialog.  I've tried a plugin on close of an incident, but that appears to only receive the old statusreason (IE before the close takes place).  I've tried on update and on create of IncidentResolution but nothing appears to be working for me.

Is there a way to retrieve this information at this stage at all?

Comment: Are you checking the input parameters for the new stage or retrieving them from CRM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try registering the plugin again on Create of the "**Incident Resolution**" entity. Not sure if you have tried this already but register it for "**Post-operation**".

This should allow you to access the **IExecutionContext.PostEntityImages** property which should have the status code you are looking for.

You will need to retrieve the related incident to if you need to update a field on it

```
Entity incident = localContext.OrganizationService.Retrieve("incident", ((EntityReference)incidentResolution["incidentid"]).Id, colSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

To be precise you have to create image in plugin registration tool either to pre or post image

But you probably dont need as image the status is part of closure, thats update and it's found in targetEntity on postUpdatePlugin ;)